# Diccionario de lista dinámica c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, lista

Antes de nada estoy programando para Unity3D, este por ejemplo no permite implementar tipos dinámico (dynamic)

Estoy intentando hacer un diccionario que alberga  un string y una lista ( que está; quiero que sea dinámica ).

Todo va bien hasta que intento coger la lista de un determinado índice del diccionario; pero no puedo implementar el RemoveAll del método List.

Objeto ItemWeapons

```
[Serializable]
public struct ItemWeapons  
{
    public int              id;
    public CommonItem       data;

    public int durability;
    public int degradationByUse;
    public int damageToEntities;
    public int damageToElements;
    public int stamina;
}
```

Objeto ItemTools

```
[Serializable]
public struct ItemTools  
{
    public int              id;
    public CommonItem       data;

    public int durability;
    public int degradationByUse;
    public int damageToEntities;
    public int damageToElements;
    public int stamina;
}
```

Script

```
public class ItemDataBase : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<ItemTools> itemTools;
    public List<ItemWeapons> itemWeapons;

    public void DinamicList(){

     dic = new Dictionary<string, object> (); // [ POSIBLE ERROR AL DEFINIR OBJECT ]

    dic.Add ("ItemTools",   itemTools);     // Variable "itemTools" es de tipo List<ItemTools>
    dic.Add ("ItemWeapons", itemWeapons);   // Variable "itemWeapons" es de tipo List<ItemWeapons>


}}
```

Método Eliminar [ POSIBLE FUTURA SOLUCIÓN ]

```
public bool Remove<T>(T data, string typeItem, int id)
    {
        var d = dic [typeItem] as List<T>;

        if (d != null)
            d.RemoveAll (x => x.id == id); 
    }
```

Algun consejo o recomendación ?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que quieres que sea "dinámica"? ¿Qué error te marca? o ¿Por qué no te funciona? ¿Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: Quiero que este diccionario pueda albergar la siguientes lista:

List<ItemWeapons>
List<ItemTools>
List<ItemLoquesea>

Ya que no puedo hacer new Dictionary <string , List>()

Comment: La cuestión es que quiero poner varios tipo de lista en un mismo diccionario. 

La forma que me que comentas es correcta, pero no da el resultado que busco. 

Gracias.

Comment: `temTools`, `ItemWeapon` y `ItemLoquesea` ¿forman parte de una jerarquía de clases? Puedes poner el codigo de ellos?

Comment: Otra pregunta. Porque habrías de juntar ambas listas en un diccionario? Hay alguna utilidad real para ello?

Comment: Es un método que utilizo en Javascript que mejora enormemente la velocidad y tamaño del script; así me evito usar tanto los "While","ForEach" y sobretodo el "Swich"

Comment: Y el código de ItemWeapon?

Comment: Puedes utilizar propiedades en lugar de campos para `ItemTools` y `ItemWeapons` ?

Comment: Pregunta sobre tu última actualización. El metodo Remove solo debe remover los que son de es tipo que coincidan con el id?

Comment: Y última pregunta, porque hay dos listas separadas en un diccionario, porque no estan todos los items en una sola lista?

Comment: Porque esta no son las única lista, tengo varias listas con diferentes atributos. He puesto esta para no alargar el código.

Comment: **He resuelto mi problema** lo he puesto en un Post aparte: [Control de listas dinámicamente. c# \[ RESUELTO \]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100323/control-de-listas-din%C3%A1micamente-c-resuelto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vas a poder tener un `List<T>` que soporte a ambos tipos de clases si estos no tienen un ancestro en común. En ese caso te recomiendo que crees una interfaz con las propiedades comunes a todas los structs que vayas a meter a la lista y que hagas que esos structs implementen la interfaz

```
public interface IItem
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public struct ItemTools: IItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public CommonItem data;

    public int durability;
    public int degradationByUse;
    public int damageToEntities;
    public int damageToElements;
    public int stamina;
}

[Serializable]
public struct ItemWeapons : IItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public CommonItem data;

    public int durability;
    public int degradationByUse;
    public int damageToEntities;
    public int damageToElements;
    public int stamina;
}
```

De esta manera tu método `DinamicList` podría quedar de esta manera

```
public void DinamicList()
{
    dic = new Dictionary<string, List<IItem>>(); // la lista de tipo IItem por lo que todas los structs que la implementen funcionaran

    dic.Add("ItemTools", itemTools);
    dic.Add("ItemWeapons", itemWeapons);

    var d = dic["ItemTools"];

    d.RemoveAll(x => x.id == id); // Puedes usar el campo id porque esta definido en IItem
}
```

Ten en cuenta que para que esto funcione los campos de `IItem` deben ser properties, no fields, por lo que he hecho ese cambio en `ItemTools` y `ItemWeapons`

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedo haber solucionado tu problema pero me parece que el diseño es un poco feo, te recomiendo que trates de replantear tu problema

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de un tipo genérico para que puedas ir agregando los elementos que deseas sin importar el tipo:

```
public void DinamicList<T>(List<T> ElementoPorAgregar)
{
    //Definición del diccionario
    Dictionary<string, List<T>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();

    if(ElementoPorAgregar.GetType() == typeof(List<ItemTools>)){
        dic.Add("ItemTools", ElementoPorAgregar);
    }

    if (ElementoPorAgregar.GetType() == typeof(List<ItemWeapons>))
    {
        dic.Add("ItemWeapons", ElementoPorAgregar);
    }
    //Eliminar llave del diccionario:    
    dic.Remove(dic.Where(t => t.Key == "ItemTools").FirstOrDefault().Key);
}
```

Comment: No tiene sentido hacerlo genérico en `T` si el código no depende de `T`

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz es a modo de ejemplo. Es posible que en este método que puse no dependeda en su totalidad el tipo `T`, pero fuera de él sí.

Comment: Con este método no puedo llamar al diccionario desde otro script. 

Estoy de acuerdo con Carlos Muñoz

Comment: @SergioGonzalezGarrido pero eso lo puedes hacer fuera del método, por eso estás trabajando con tipos genéricos. Por cierto, ¿a qué te refieres con "otro script"?

Comment: En otro foro de ayuda me estan diciendo el uso de system.reflection para llamar al método RemoveAll.

Comment: @SergioGonzalezGarrido ¿tienes algún ejemplo que podamos ver?

Comment: @Flxtr me refiero poder llamar desde otro método la variable donde esta el diccionario y poder manipular el dicionar como: Añadir , buscar o eliminar.

Answer (score 1):

Solución aportada por @Carlos Muñoz

Así queda el código final.

// Interface de los items

```
public interface IItem
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string type { get; set; }
}
```

// Item ejemplo Weapons

```
[Serializable]
public struct ItemTools : IItem 
{
    public int              id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public CommonItem       data;

    public int durability;
    public int degradationByUse;
    public int damageToEntities;
    public int damageToElements;
    public int stamina;
}
```

// Creación de lista dinamica

```
    public void CreateDictionary()
    {

        dic = new Dictionary<string,  List<IItem>> ();

        dic.Add ("ItemTools",   itemTools);     // Variable "itemTools" es de tipo List<ItemTools>
        dic.Add ("ItemWeapons", itemWeapons);   // Variable "itemWeapons" es de tipo List<ItemWeapons>

    }
```

// Eliminación de item

```
public bool Remove(string typeItem, int id)
    {

        var d = dic[typeItem];

        d.RemoveAll( x => x.id == id && x.type == typeItem);
}
```