# ¿ Cómo controlar listas de forma dinámica?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy intentado hacer una agrupación de lista y poderla gestionar de forma dinámica sin que un humano tenga que actuar.

Digamos que quiero hacer un método que mediante un string **recupere una List** cualquiera, **evitando el uso de switch o métodos de control elseIf y el Casteo de la misma List<>**, ya que quiero no tener que implementar más código de lo necesario.

Sobretodo tener en **una variable** todas las lista y tener **acceso a ellas de manera global** en la misma clase.

```
public class MiClass
{
   // [ Primera idea ]
   Dictionary<string, List<T>> DicList; // Pero no se puede porque T no entra en contexto

   // [ Segunda idea ] 
   Dictionary < string, List<object> DicListObj; // No me se implementa como yo quiero

   // [ Tercera idea ]
   public SortedList lists; // Esta me funciona bastante bien pero al recuperar la lista, esta me devuelve un ** object **

   // [ Metodo de ejemplo ]
   void ManipulationList( string person )
   {

       var listTool = list["ListTool"];

       listTool.FindAll( x => x.name == person ); // Esto no se puede hacer si no esta casteada a List<T>

   }
}
```

De momento me auto contesté la pregunta y use los métodos de GetType para ejecutar los métodos de List que vienen en el objeto; lo suyo estaría bien poder castear el objeto evitando el uso de los siguiente elementos ya que requieren de persona física para implementarlo.

```
var listTool = list["ListTool"] as List<ListTool>;
var listTool = (List<ListTool>)list["ListTool"];
```

**Se podría convertir el objeto => array => list  o object => list?** Porque podría usar el método *GetEnumerator* mediante *GetType* y después usar el método *ToList* de los *Enumerator* ?

Comment: Recomiendo cerrar esta "pregunta" ya que en realidad no hay ninguna

Comment: La pregunta tal como está no encaja en las normas del sitio. Deberías modificarla de tal manera que fuera realmente una pregunta, algo así como: "Como puedo manejar listas de distintos tipos en una lista genérica?" . Edita la pregunta o corre un serio peligro de ser cerrada :)

Comment: Gracias, solo quiero aportar mi conocimiento y agradecer vuestro apoyo y ayuda.

Comment: Y realmente se agradece. Las preguntas autorespondidas son bien recibidas aqui, pero deben estar acordes a [ask] :)

Answer (score 2):

Imaginemos que tenemos una clase serializada:

```
[Serializable]
public class Tool 
{
    public string globalName;

    // Otros métodos y atributos [ ... ]

    public string GetGlobalName()
    {
        return this.globalName;
    }
}
```

Después en otra clase creamos las lista:

```
public class ItemDatabase 
{
   // [ BASE DE DATOS ]
   public List<Tool>   tools;
   public List<Weapon> weapons;

   // [ CONTROLADOR DE LISTADO DINÁMICO ]
   public SortedList lists;

    void CreateDynamicList() 
    {   
        // Inicializar SortedList [ System.Collections ]
        lists = new SortedList ();

        // Añadir listas
        lists.Add ("Tools", tools);
        lists.Add ("Weapons", weapons);

    }

    // [ Continúa más abajo ]
```

Creamos un método de invocación de métodos

```
    Invoke( object main, string invocation, object obj )
    {

        object[] data = new object[]{ obj };


        if (obj == null) data = null;


        main.GetType ().GetMethod (invocation).Invoke (main,data);
    }

    // [ Continúa más abajo ]
```

Creamos los métodos que se usan en List<> para esta clase;

```
    public void Add( string type , object data )
    {           
        Invoke ( lists[type], "Add", data );
    }

    public void RemoveAt( string type , int id )
    {           
        Invoke ( lists[type], "RemoveAt", id );
    }
```

Gracias a esta clase que he creado no tengo la necesidad de saber el genérico de la lista ( List< T > ) he ir añadiendo tantas lista como quiera y olvidarme de los Switch y IfElse.

Tengo implementado otros métodos, si queréis saber más los [subiré a youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMWNwjk3gmNhFD1fi4EyLjg) pronto.

Gracias a todos los que me han ayudado en stackoverflow;

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de añadir [RESUELTO] al título, marca tu propia respuesta como aceptada. Del mismo modo, sabemos que la pregunta está relacionada con c# gracias a los tags, no hace falta tampoco en el título.

Comment: Podrás marcar  tu respuesta como aceptada dentro de 48h

Comment: Gracias, así lo haré.